# Parsing a Parsed String

Tags: c, parsing, csv

I am creating a C programme which reads in a CSV file line-byline.  So each line is assigned like this:

```
sch = strtok (line,",");
```

The first token (and only needed one) is a date-time stamp in the form: `2013-12-13 09:15:00.000`

How can I then split this token up, using the space) to only store the time section of the token `09:15:00.000`?

Thanks for the help - I've updated my code here to reflect the changes suggested below, but my programme crashes when you try to execute it:

```
while ( fgets (line, 512, file) != NULL )
{   
    sch = strtok (line,",");
    if (sch != NULL)
    {
        sch = strtok (line," ");
        sch = strtok (NULL," ");
        fputs(sch,filetwo);
        fputc('\n',filetwo);
        break;
    }
sch = strtok (NULL, ",");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then, you'll call `strtok` again. See below,

```
while ( fgets (line, 512, file) != NULL )
{   
    char * tmp = strtok (line,",");
    if (tmp != NULL)
    {
        sch = strtok (tmp," ");
        sch = strtok (NULL," ");
        fputs(sch,filetwo);
        fputc('\n',filetwo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good for also getting rid of the pointless `while` and `break`.

Comment: Thanks for this - my programme is now crashing when I attempt to execute.  I've updated the code in the original question.

Comment: @user1920482 I've still got a small problem in that my programme crashes, if you can help?

Comment: @DustinCook: use the edited code above if it's ok. If not, could you post the whole source so that I can examine further.

Comment: @DustinCook: I run your code. It finished successfully. Check if your input file is in correct format. http://pastebin.com/VYdNjuqb

Comment: @user1920482 If I comment out the `NULL` it worked as expected.

Comment: @DustinCook: That's good. But which __NULL__ did you comment out? (- just my curiosity).

Answer (score 1):

Call the function `strtok` with a NULL pointer instead of the string to get the next result.

Keep in mind the the C library has a state. It remembers the last token and uses it for further calls. So you can't return the the next ',' separated token when you started the ' ' tokenization.

```
if (sch != NULL)
{
    sch = strtok(line, " ");
    time_section = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this instead, there is no need to use `strtok()` since you only need the first csv-field.

```
while ( fgets (line, 512, file) != NULL )
{   
  char* datetime = strchr(line,",");
  if (datetime != NULL)
  {
    char *spc = strchr( datetime, ' ' ); // find space
    if ( spc != NULL )
    {
      char* timeonly = spc + 1; // move past spc, point to time part
    ...
```